# Do not understand why I am getting this Laravel Illuminate Error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

This is the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'desk.messages' doesn't exist 
(SQL: insert into `messages` (`id`, `users_id`, `reps_id`, `comment`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
values 
(1, 1, 1, testing, 2014-09-0 5 14:07:38, 2014-09-05 14:07:38))
```

I have the table protected in the method:

```
 /**
 * Connection name
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'messages';
```

And this is my Seeder:

```
 use Desk\Records\MessageRecord;

 class MessageSeeder extends Seeder {
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $message = [
        'testUser' => [
            'id' => '1',
            'users_id' => '1',
            'reps_id' => '1',
            'comment' => 'testing',
        ]
    ];

    foreach( $message as $message )
    {
        MessageRecord::create($message);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: That's not true, Laravel recommends protected http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

Comment: That was a response to a deleted comment not Jack's issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the table first, you can do that via [Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations).

Comment: i did create the table

Comment: " Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'desk.messages' doesn't exist " is an error from your database server telling you it doesn't exist. Please double check using a your favorite database viewer that it's actually there.

Answer (score 1):

It's tellin you that your database `desks` does not contain a table named `messages`.

Create the table using Laravel migrations or manually.